# jquery UI.js prevents to load dynamically loaded select menu

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I tried to load dynamically loaded select menu for my page using Ajax/PHP. But jquery UI plugging prevents to load that dynamically loaded data. So I can't see nothing when i change the first select menu.

My code like this.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function($) {
  var list_target_id = 'list-target'; //first select list ID
  var list_select_id = 'list-select'; //second select list ID
  var initial_target_html = '<option value="">-Select-</option>'; //Initial prompt for target select

  $('#'+list_target_id).html(initial_target_html); //Give the target select the prompt option

  $('#'+list_select_id).change(function(e) {
    //Grab the chosen value on first select list change
    var selectvalue = $(this).val();

    //Display 'loading' status in the target select list
    $('#'+list_target_id).html('<option value="">Loading...</option>');

    if (selectvalue == "") {
        //Display initial prompt in target select if blank value selected
       $('#'+list_target_id).html(initial_target_html);
    } else {
      //Make AJAX request, using the selected value as the GET
      $.ajax({url: 'loadcity.php?svalue='+selectvalue,
             success: function(output) {
                //alert(output);
                $('#'+list_target_id).html(output);
            },
          error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(xhr.status + " "+ thrownError);
          }});
        }
    });
});
</script>

<form method="post">
<div class="select-country">
<label>District</label>
<select name="list-select" id="list-select">
<option value="">Please select..</option>
<?php
$sel_dis2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM district", $connection);
confirm_query($sel_dis2);
while($dis2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($sel_dis2)){
?>
<option value="<?php echo $dis2["id_district"]; ?>"><?php echo $dis2["district"]; ?></option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>
</div>
<div class="select-state">
<label>City</label> 
<select name="list-target" id="list-target"></select>
</div>
</form>
```

I tested the code without including jquery UI and it worked properly. But i want to add jquery UI for this page. This is the php file

```
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password", "database");

$selectvalue = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_GET['svalue']);

mysqli_select_db($connection, "database");
$result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT city.id_city, city.city  FROM city WHERE city.district_id = '$selectvalue'");

echo '<option value="">-Select-</option>';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
    echo '<option value="'.$row['id_city'].'">' . $row['city'] . "</option>";
    //echo $row['drink_type'] ."<br/>";
  }

mysqli_free_result($result);
mysqli_close($connection);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something else is breaking your select. Tested at jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ddpdhr5a/

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
  var list_target_id = 'list-target'; //first select list ID
  var list_select_id = 'list-select'; //second select list ID
  var initial_target_html = '<option value="">-Select-</option>'; //Initial prompt for target select

  $('#'+list_target_id).html(initial_target_html); //Give the target select the prompt option

  $('#'+list_select_id).change(function(e) {
    //Grab the chosen value on first select list change
    var selectvalue = $(this).val();

    //Display 'loading' status in the target select list
    $('#'+list_target_id).html('<option value="">Loading...</option>');

    if (selectvalue == "") {
        //Display initial prompt in target select if blank value selected
       $('#'+list_target_id).html(initial_target_html);
    } else {
      //Make AJAX request, using the selected value as the GET
      $.ajax({url: 'loadcity.php?svalue='+selectvalue,
             success: function(output) {
                //alert(output);
                $('#'+list_target_id).html(output);
            },
          error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(xhr.status + " "+ thrownError);
          }});
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<form method="post">
<div class="select-country">
<label>District</label>
<select name="list-select" id="list-select">
<option value="">Please select..</option>
<option value="something">Something</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="select-state">
<label>City</label> 
<select name="list-target" id="list-target"></select>
</div>
</form>
```

This seems to work perfectly, although I had to remove the PHP, naturally, and just use some mock location

Comment: I didn't add loadcity.php file here. It works properly with php and mysql database. but when i include jquery UI then it doesn't work.

Comment: The examples use both jQuery and jQuery UI. Are they supposed to do something more?

Comment: yes i want to use both. they need to use for the UI of the website.

Comment: Oh my... I KNOW. I'm asking if the example are doing something less than what you want to be doing? Because the example posted has BOTH jQuery AND jQuery UI loaded, and the dropdowns seem to be working. Since you haven't told us WHAT doesn't work when you load both, it's hard to know what is causing the problem.

Comment: If you don't mind please check the both links given below.   http://www.marryme.lk/stest.php                                                  http://www.marryme.lk/index_test.php

Comment: You declare `$(document).ready(function()` twice, with two batches of `<script>` tags in your non-working example. Try combining them both into one `<script>` tag, and one `$(document).ready(function()` and see if that helps. You also have quite a bit of 404-errors, missing JS and CSS and such - while that might not have anything to do with the error, the best thing is to either fix those errors, or remove the call to the files while testing. Especially js-errors may propagate, and make other elements malfunction.

Comment: Actually it happens when i add jquery UI to the code.  marryme.lk/stest.php - without jquery UI and  marryme.lk/stest2.php - including UI

Comment: If your version of jQuery is accurate, you're using a way too old version of jQuery. See if updating jQuery helps, perhaps? You seem to be using version 1.12, which is horribly outdated, and the jQuery UI-version you're using should be used with jQuery 1.7+

Comment: Checked them all. Only problem with jquery UI. I removed it temporary. http://www.marryme.lk/stest2.php now it is working. But i want to add that UI.